# Nokia browser sees large scrolling portion

Tags: java, css, jsp, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I have one captive portal site which looks fine in Samsung mobile while in nokia it will display large blank portion of browser other then require content.

is there any solution to remove that large blank portion ?

I have created one test page and include my content page inside it it's work perfect but 
When i use following code to include other page as my application use the same it's create same problem

Code

```
   <FRAMESET COLS="0,*" frameborder="no">
      <FRAME SRC="" NAME="livebar" SCROLLING="auto" border="0">
      <FRAME SRC="path of jsp to include" NAME="mail_main" SCROLLING="auto" border="0" />

    </FRAMESET>
```

Comment: You should post relevant code.

Comment: Also, Samsung phones are built with Android and Nokia phones are built with either Windows Phone or Symbian (older smart phones only).

Comment: I don't see any jQuery or jQuery Mobile files that have to be included. I also don't see the page structure that you would use for a jQuery Mobile website.

Comment: Please check my edited question that might help u to answer.